# C++ Boost convert UNIX Timestamp to MySQL compatible DATETIME String

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime, unix, boost

I'm trying to convert a UNIX Timestamp which is in long to a Date Time string that needs to be stored in MySQL, in this format `2016-02-01 03:15:10`

This is what i have so far. Its not working on the time extraction part. I couldn't find any constructor for  boost::posix_time::time_duration that can take directly a boost::posix_time::ptime object. So i tried to include a workaround. But it doesn't work in the hours() part.

```
static inline std::string getDateTime(long timestamp) {
      std::stringstream date_str;
      boost::posix_time::ptime pt_1 = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(timestamp);

      /* workaround to somehow get a time_duration object constructed */
      boost::posix_time::ptime pt_temp = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(0);

      boost::gregorian::date d = pt_1.date();

      boost::posix_time::time_duration td = pt_1 - pt_temp;

      /* construct the Date Time string */
      date_str << d.year() << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << d.month().as_number() << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << d.day() << " "
               << td.hours() << ":" << td.minutes() << ":" << td.seconds();

      return date_str.str();
    }
```

With an Timestamp input such as `1455892259` i'm getting this `2016-02-19 404414:30:59` as a DateTime String from the function. How to actually get the correct Date Time string which in this case would be `2016-02-19 14:30:59`. Using Boost for this is compulsory.

**UPDATE**

This is the final working function rewritten using the answer provided by Jarra McIntyre below.

```
static inline std::string getDateTime(long timestamp) {
      std::stringstream date_str;
      boost::posix_time::ptime pt_1 = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(timestamp);

      boost::gregorian::date d = pt_1.date();

      auto td = pt_1.time_of_day();

      /* construct the Date Time string */
      date_str << d.year() << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << d.month().as_number() << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << d.day() << " "
               << td.hours() << ":" << td.minutes() << ":" << td.seconds();

      return date_str.str();
    }
```

Comment: Will this do "from_unixtime" in the manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: Well yes but i actually have to insert the DATETIME string into MySQL. The timestamp value is being fetched from a service, which i need to convert into a DATETIME string in order to insert it in the table along with the Timestamp. So far i haven't came across a method to convert Timestamp to DATETIME directly during Insertion so i'm using the method i posted above. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: datetime is not a string. Plenty of conversions in MySql - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Yes but it needs to be in a String which will be added in the full Insert Query String and this whole Query will be send to MySQL

Comment: No it does not. Bind the variables (prevents SQL injection for a start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
auto td = pt_1.time_of_day();
```

There is no need for a workaround to get the time of day. The number of hours being displayed in your question is probably the number of hours between 1970-01-01 00:00 and 2016-02-19 14:00. For your method of getting the time_duration to work you would have to construct a ptime on the same day not at unix time 0.